# Internal server git asking for password?

Tags: git

wondering how i can avoid entering my password when pushing and pulling in GIT on the same server?

My directory structure looks like:

```
/home/gitrepo
/home/site/public/contents(.git)etc
```

I think it has something to do with user or group (chown / chgrp) being different. Should I just generate ssh keys ON the server, that doesn’t make sense though. There must be a way to git on the same machine through different users dirs?

Comment: Can you paste the contents of `git remote -v` and tell us with what command you're trying to push?

Comment: You need to show how you define your remotes otherwise no-one can say. Also you can use just the local file-system as an remote, so you do not need to input anything at all if you have all rights on the local file-system.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the various [git protocols](http://git-scm.com/book/ch4-1.html), which are all in the form of:

```
(protocol)://[user@](servername)[:port]/(path)
```

A file protocol will ask for password if you don't have the necessary (read/write) rights to access/modify the target.

An ssh protocol would be more appropriate, providing your ssh daemon is up, and has in its path git.
If so, generate a public/private keys in `/home/gitrepo/.ssh`, and public the public key in the `/home/site/.ssh/authorized_keys` files, as described in the ["Public Key-Based Configuration" section](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html#13075) of this [ssh page](http://oreilly.com/catalog/sshtdg/chapter/ch08.html).